# How to drop sequential duplicate words in sentences?

Tags: python, regex

I have the following strings.

```
s = [
  "2019 2019",
  "he is angry angry",
  "she is hungry"
]
```

I need to drop all sequential duplicate words or numbers inside the same string.

The expected output:

```
s = [
  "2019"
  "he is angry",
  "she is hungry"
]
```

How can I do it using regex expressions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use ordered set - >

```
# pip install ordered_set
from ordered_set import OrderedSet
s = [
  "2019 2019",
  "he is angry angry",
  "she is hungry"
]

result =[' '.join(OrderedSet(i.split())) for i in s]
```

**Output-**

```
['2019', 'he is angry', 'she is hungry']
```

Comment: I was going to suggest the same thing- clean solution. To make the space splitting more evident I would do: `sep = " "`. Then,  `i.split(sep)`.

Comment: It does not work for: "Well, equal to a year and a half before 2020, in 2019 2019."

Comment: @Fluxy It's one of the edge cases - here '2019' and '2019.' are 2 diff words because of an extra dot at the end.

Comment: Yes, I know. Should I drop the dot at the end or could there be a flexible solution with this sense?

Comment: I'll say remove all punctuations if you don't need them. you can use - s.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)) to remove them here 's' is the initial string